# How to send input value from component to modal

Tags: angular

I hope you can help with this problem I'm having.

I need to send the input value from component 1 to another input value in component 2.
component 2 is a modal, which tags are in component 1.

So once the user enters a value in the first input, then clicks the button which saves the info into a service called 'info' and opens the modal, the written value must be already loaded in the component 2 input field, that is why I tried to initialize value with FormControl. This is what I have.

**Component 1 HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="forms mb-2">
         <label for="input-number">New Number</label>
         <div class="input-group">
            <input id="input-number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="123456789" aria-label="NewNumber" aria-describedby="input-number" formControlName="addNumber">
            <div class="input-group-append">
               <div class="input-group-text" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="openModal()">
                     Search
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   <div class="row" class="text-center">
      <div style="text-align:center;" class="text-center">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newNumber">
             Add New Number
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>

   </div>
</form>
<app-new-number [id]="'newNumber'" (answer)="onOperate($event)"></app-new-number>
```

**This is what I have in component 2 HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" [id]="id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="mb-4"><u>New Data</u></h1>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form [formGroup]="formModal">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                        <label for="inp-number">New Number</label>
                           <input id="inp-number" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Number" aria-describedby="inp-num" formControlName='inpNewNumb'>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>      
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="text-align:right;">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
                  Save
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Component 2 TS:**

```
export class ModalNewNumber implements OnInit {
    @Input() id;
    formModal: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {
       this.info = _sharedService.sender;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.formModal = new FormGroup({
          'inpNewNumb': new FormControl({value: this.info.newNumber},
          [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')])
       });
    }
}
```

So far I just can save the info from first input in service. When I assign value to input 2. I just get [object Object]. I tried to assign value in component 2 ts, out ngOnInit, but I got an error.
I think it is because the structure of modal is created before I assign values, so when it loads, already has object value. I don't know. Please help :D

Comment: Can you create demo in stackblitz?

Comment: Post your service code here or create stackblitz